# How to add string in front of every character?

Tags: python, string, indexing, range, out

I tried this but I can't.

I want to add `"pp"` string in front of every character of input.

```py
x=str(input("give me the characters"))
print("pp"+x[0]+"pp"+x[1]+"sa"+x[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` to add `pp`. For example:

```py
x = input("give me the characters: ")
print("pp".join(["", *x]))
```

Prints:

```
give me the characters: abcd
ppappbppcppd
```